# Implicit typing from generic parent class does not work as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider an abstract class `AbstractDbService` to be generic like so:

```
abstract class AbstractDbService<T extends Record<string, any>> {
    public async persistEntity(entity: T) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I inherit from this class and I do not explicitly type the `entity` parameter, I get the error `Parameter 'entity' implicitly has an 'any' type`:

[image]

This feels kind of insufficient. I feel like using the concept of types and the concept inheritance together, this should exactly end up with `entity` being type of `T`.

So my questions are: Why do I have to explicitly type `entity`? Doesn't this make typing in the parent class useless? And is there any way to use "correct implicit typing" in a way that `entity` is implicitly of type `T`?

---

The full example can also be seen here on the [typescript playground (with typing hints)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgIxgXhgbwFA2zADgUwCcIBLaALhgAooBDBAG30ukJLAHMAaGfMKElACelWmCEBKFAD4YABUIgAtmXwA6QvgggGAN3w1CAV3wSMAXwwZ6rWsFjAGtCBBgBBBLfsARBAGUiXRJgfAAeABVeAA8oPjhXACV8UEI4UNZ2bhgxIWlZTBw8RVj7fDgYOkZmGAzOAG4rQtBIKGN7EEJqSqYWVsypAsKcKAALMjVu-BQK+iYGwsssHFwjRmDsiCEwYDwiUmgAUX5BISo+AWFKcIGloZhNKCNCMGyAd1pBeAQ1AmIyKBoYwgE1m+B45xOEnmOEsi0czlc4S0UF8AUIQRC0ViYHi7k8rTsKP8gWCYTQMBIcEoYCMSgQRB4YFoSmqtQ4MHM0kG2GarCM7U6VBud2wECMvyoACJYtAAPqTSVQ24cxrLVYMdbOLY7X77KBHC6nCHCYUikgAM2oxqEaiZLJQyFQksV6GVIoqI0UrxgYHw3oOhEUhClADlmVMlEZoD6QLB6bwlLhhIroXdLO6Hk8XmLfj89v8DSczscTamVeYgA) or in the following code snippet:

```js
const db = {
    persist: (table: string, entity: any) => Promise.resolve(true)
}

abstract class AbstractDbService<T extends Record<string, any>> {
    protected table: string;

    constructor (table: string) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public async persistEntity(entity: T) {
        return await db.persist(this.table, entity);
    }
}

class TestDbService extends AbstractDbService<{ id: number, name: string }>{
    constructor () {
        super("test_table");
    }

    public async persistEntity(entity) {
        if (entity.name === "") {
            throw new Error("Name must not be empty");
        }
        return super.persistEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: TS will not infer types for parameters from the base class. There was a proposal to do so but changing it now might be a breaking change

Comment: Hmm, ok. Thank you for your answer, even though that was not what I wanted to hear :D Do you have any references to the proposal?

Comment: Answering myself: I found https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16590, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16590 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you would think they could just add a new setting that would not be enabled by default for that.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911 Says it all. Interesting topic actually. Looks like they have, and are considering what I suggested with adding the capability of infering the extended classes type to the parameter via specific TSConfig settings/flags. The examples shown on that issue actually put typescripts limitations into perspective, or rather it puts the typing of any dynamic language into perspective.